Using R languageserver in RStudio for code formatting
I have recently switched from using VSCode for my R projects to RStudio and found that the automatic code formatting in VSCode is much better compared to RStudios Reformat Code (Ctrl+Shift+A). I have also tried out the styler but this also has sever shortcomings such as not breaking very long lines (on the otherhand, RStudios Reformat Code (Ctrl+Shift+A) breaks a line after every single element in a vector which is a complete overkill).
So my question is if it is possible to use "VSCode like" code formatting in RStudio and have a similar functionality to Format on Type.
Any help is much appreciated!
Cheers!
